# How to prevent Dell desktop from making a chime whenever my monitor goes to sleep?

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-computers

I have a Windows 10 Dell desktop which makes a chime whenever its monitor goes to sleep.

The monitor is shared with another PC and the Dell is connected via a DP-HDMI cable. The Dell also has an internal speaker. Sometimes, I use the other PC and left the Dell to do its background job. But when the monitor goes blank, the Dell will make a chime (like when a device is connected/disconnected). I think the sound is generated because the monitor has speakers and when the monitor goes to sleep, the sound switched to the Dell's internal speaker.

I can disable the sound by removing the chime from the sound profile. But that means I will stop hearing sound when device connect/disconnect too. Is there a better way?

Comment: Which monitor model? Is it also a USB dock?

Comment: A view Sonic perhaps?  I have a new one in the basement that does that

Comment: Half-way approach: use a softer and/or shorter System Sound. You can use any short .wav file, even a single "click".

Comment: It is an Asus monitor. It does not have a USB hub. It has a built-in speaker that can play audio from the HDMI. That's about it. But it has multiple HDMI ports which is why I am sharing it with another PC.